# What is the difference between hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size and hibernate.jdbc.batch_size?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, orm

I am trying to tune my application, came across some blogs speaking about the batch fetch and batch select and putting my understanding as follows.

- `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` - Used to specify number of rows to be fetched in a select query.
- `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` - Used to specify number of inserts or updates to be carried out in a single database hit.

Please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not? Also what are the *optimal values* for the above parameters..

Comment: My understanding is that fetch_size has to do with lazy loading of Collections, while batch_size has to do with batching things, like batch inserts or batch updates.  As far as "optimal values" go, I think that is a tuning issue that is case-by-case.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Both of these options set properties within the JDBC driver. In the first case, `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` sets the statement's fetch size within the JDBC driver, that is the number of rows fetched when there is more than a one row result on select statements.

In the second case, `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` determines the number of updates (inserts, updates and deletes) that are sent to the database at one time for execution. This parameter is necessary to do batch inserts, but must be coupled with the ordered inserts parameter and the JDBC driver's capability to rewrite the inserts into a batch insert statement.

See [this link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/sect-Performance_Tuning_Guide-Entity_Beans-Batching_Database_Operations.html)

Answer (score 27):

Your assumptions are correct.

### hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size

The `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size` Hibernate configuration property is used for setting the JDBC [`Statement#setFetchSize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setFetchSize(int)) property for every statement that Hibernate uses during the currently running Persistence Context.

Usually, you don't need to set this property as the default is fine, especially for MySQL and PostgreSQL which fetch the entire `ResultSet` in a single database roundtrip. Because Hibernate traverses the entire `ResultSet`, you are better off fetching all rows in a single shot instead of using multiple roundtrips.

Only for Oracle, you might want to set it since the default `fetchSize` is just [`10`](https://vladmihalcea.com/resultset-statement-fetching-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/).

### hibernate.jdbc.batch_size

The [`hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) property is used to batch multiple INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements together so that they can be set in a single database call.

If you set this property, you are better off setting these two as well:

- `hibernate.order_inserts` to `true`
- `hibernate.order_updates` to `true`

Comment: _"Because Hibernate traverses the entire ResultSet, you are better off fetching all rows in a single shoot instead of using multiple roundtrips."_ not necessarily true. It will need more memory and it will take longer until the first row is available. Depending on the exact fetch behavior of a JDBC driver, fetching in blocks might perform better and consume less memory for result set internals.

Comment: That sounds like the JDBC Driver responsibility to use the right fetching strategy by defaul, like SQL Server using adaptive buffering. Anyway, this setting overrides the default behaviour, and often, it will perform worse with JPA and Hibernate, at least.

Comment: When I set fetch size with postgresql it actually slowed down my data retrieval

Answer (score 0):

Fetch size does `Statement.setFetchSize()` while batch size is for Hibernate batching. Both configuration parameters are explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-jdbc-properties). For hibernate batch refer [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding seems quite correct. I would refer you to the JBOSS documentation on Hibernate, the following chapter is on [Batch processing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/batch/Batching.html).  And this one on [tweaking performance](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/5/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-performance_tuning_guide-entity_beans-batching_database_operations).

It's a good, easy to read source. It gives some suggestions on optimal values, but as CodeChimp mentioned, tuning is best done case by case and is a repeatable process over time.