# Batch size not working with Google Guice + JPA + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice, guice-persist

I am using *Google Guice* as dependency injection and Transaction purpose along with JPA and Hibernate.

I have added `<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="20" />` in my `persistence.xml` file.

Here is my save entity list DAO code :

```
@Transactional
public void save(final List<T> entities) {
    final EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    for (final T entity : entities) {
        if (!em.contains(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
        }
    }
}
```

Why it is not inserting in Database in batch of size 20 ?

Comment: If you comment out the if what happens?

Comment: @Lajos Arpad  I am inserting 100 entities . It is inserting sequentially because I can see 100 insertion statement in log.

Comment: Which version of Hibernate do you use in this project? Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129503/2849346 ?