# How to batch the fetches when pulling huge number of records from Oracle using JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Java application where we use spring data JPA to query our oracle database. For one use case, I need to fetch all the records present in the table. Now the table has record count of 400,000 thousand and it might grow in the near future. I don't feel comfortable pulling all records into the JVM since we don't know how large they can be. So, I want to configure the code to fetch specific number of records at a time say 50,000 and process before it goes to next 50,000. Is there a way I can achieve this with JPA? I came across this JDBC property that can be used with hibernate `hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size`. What I am trying to understand is if I use `repository.findAll()` returning `List<Entity>`How can a fetch Size work in this case? because List will have all the entities. I was also looking into repository methods returning `Stream<>`, not sure if I have to use that. Please do suggest. If there can be better solution for this use case?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think fetch size has benefits if you need to fetch everything into a static collection like a list, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129503/995891 - even if it would do multiple fetch operations you'd still load all data into memory at once. How streaming and fetch size behaves seems to depends on more than just hibernate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55952655/995891

Comment: you can get only part of data with pagination, but question is what you want to do with each portion of data? Try to describe

Comment: @notAPPP I just need to execute small logic on each db record and save it in-memory.

Answer (score 0):

With JPA you can use the Pagination feature, means you tell the Repository how many result should be present at one  page. (E.g. 50 000)

For more information follow up here https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-pagination